# Type 'Observable<unknown[]>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<User[]>'

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, observable

I got this error:

```
Type 'Observable<unknown[]>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<User[]>'.
```

I'm trying to fetch data from firestore.

I use Observable for the first time (I watch some videos about observable, but here I can't use why I do not understand).
Can you help me?

by the way, user is this:

```
export interface User {
  email: string;
  uid: string;
}
```

my codes here:

```
  usersCollection: AngularFirestoreCollection<User>;
  users: Observable<User[]>;
   constructor(public auth: AngularFireAuth, public db: AngularFirestore) {
    **this.users(problem here)** = this.db.collection("users").valueChanges();
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can fix it by passing the `User` type as a generic parameter to the `collection` like the following:

```js
this.users = this.db.collection<User>("users").valueChanges();
```

This will return `Observable<User[]>` from the `valueChanges`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **any[]** after the variable name to get rid of this error